# Is there a way to keep node js cluster send() messages in order

Tags: node.js, express

Using some added sequence checks below, I see that messages are sometimes arriving out of order and that breaks the code.
I am thinking I must queue up out-of-order messages upon receive to make sure things get processed in order.
Is this just the nature of NodeJS ?

```
// In the master process:
msg.sequence = next_sequence[i]++;
worker[i].send(msg)

// In worker(s):
process.on("message",handler);
....
var last_sequence = 0;
function handler(msg){
if ( last_sequence + 1 != msg.sequence ) console.log(...);
last_sequence = msg.sequence;
```

Comment: Do you have one worker that send unordered messages? Are you using child_process or the new worker threads?

Comment: There are 4 cluster workers.
I think I know 1 issue, but I don't know if that is the sole source of random failures.
send(X) may copy the passed object at a random time later.
If the same object (with some new contents) is sent again too soon, 2 copies can get sent with the sequence numbers.

This would mean that
let something = { id:1543, val1:1, val2:0 };
X.send(something);
...
something.val1 = 0;
...
X.send(something);
...
something.val1 = 0;
...
something.val1 = 1;

Comment: (Sorry, I did not know about the 5 minute edit limit)
Continuing..."something" example above could means that val1 is received twice as 0 or twice as 1 randomly.
Is the only solution to deep copy or stringify the data before passing to send() (which will do so again soon) ?

Answer (score 0):

After using send(JSON.stringify(msg)) and JSON.parse when receiving, the behavior seems more deterministic and message sequence numbers are in order.

So it seems that send() does not immediately copy the data and it can still be changed some short while after calling send().

Can anyone confirm this ?